# Запоминание просмотренных элементов JS

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.
На страницу из бд загружаются  данные (как только пользователь доходит до конца, загружаются еще одни). Мне нужно запоминать просмотренные элементы и при обновлении страницы визуально поменять их отображение, к примеру, сменить фон блока. Данные на странице выглядят примерно так. Как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Сложность в том, что js вижу 3 раз в жизни и, скорее всего, более не понадобится. Поэтому и не знаю как реализовать.

```
    title: some title 0

    title: some title 1

    title: some title 2

function render(books) {

for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
var item = document.createElement('ul');
item.classList = ['book']
item.innerText = 'title: ' + books[i]['title'];
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(item);
```

}}

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса. С чем трудности?

Comment: перед загрузкой новых имеющимся добавляете класс какой-то для отметки

Comment: трудность в том, что я не знаю js. как это сделать?

Comment: После редактирования вопрос стал более понятен. Чтобы запоминать просмотренные элементы, нужно либо использовать куки, либо локальное хранилище. У каждого просмотренного элемента должен быть идентификатор, который и будет записан в кеш браузера. Останется только считывать это при загрузке элементов

Comment: функция грузит данные из бд, если данных нет, очевидно не грузит. код неудобно вставлять сюда, сейчас выше

Comment: Если у загружаемых данных есть идентификатор и это порядковый номер, то здесь даже проще, можно записать в кэш браузера последний полученный идентификатор

Comment: На заметку. Если вижу цикл через `for`, то сразу становится понятно что кодер либо мало ознакомлен с языком и его возможностями, либо это чел какой-то старой закалки  Пользуясь случаем, хочу передать привет маме, другу из трущоб и Grundy, который постоянно удаляет мои комментарии, люблю его 

Comment: спасибо, да, у данных есть порядковый номер, в самом начале загружается 9 штук, затем по 10 идет. как записать в кэш бразуера?

Comment: в моем случае, я не знаю js вообще, на python/django пишу. кое-как 5 функций реализовал на js, а на бэке fastapi, не спрашивайте зачем)

Comment: @НикитаСмяцкий к счастью всё легко гуглится. В какую сторону копать уже знаешь, это cookie или localstorage. Записываешь число 9. В скрипте проверяешь если больше 9, то данные новые